Can CSS grid Lines be hidden when debugging using chrome dev tools?
Hello I am trying to fix spacing on a modal I am working on and the background is a grid of images. I don't want to disable css grid because that will make me feel more crazy when I am trying to debug css issues.
I would just like to find a way to disable the overlay I see when I open the chrome dev tools. Does anyone know a way I can do this?
here is an example:


Do you not have a set of checkboxes for displaying / hiding grid and flexbox overlays under the Layout tab?

@Phil I didn't know that was a thing? yeah I do and that fixes the issue. Can you please make an Answer and I will approve it

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/grid#overlays

See Inspect CSS grid layouts - Grid overlays

Enable overlay views of multiple grids
You can enable overlay views of multiple grids


Toggle the checkboxes assigned to each grid layout element to enable / disable the overlay.
There is also a similar control for Flexbox overlays.
